# jvector map rendering issue on chrome & firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jvectormap

jvector map gets render as (very small) shown in hyperlink's.

[image]

Comment: question is far to sparse to be able to help. Please edit your post and provide something we can assist with. Maybe some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

jvector map is getting  rendered very small and use to give error in browser     console.As we resize the browser , jvector map gets rendered properly .

All related images are linked with url
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YybWi.png